# Apache FOP use data from Service for PDF

Tags: java, apache, pdf, apache-fop

i want to use Apache FOP to generate a PDF with data provided by a ServiceClass i wrote (some Strings and Arrays with Objects in them).

In a sample implementation the template.fo looks like this:

```
    #foreach( $salesRow in $salesRows )
       <fo:table-row height="1cm">
            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="3">
                 <fo:block>
                     $salesRow.var1
                 </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="3">
                 <fo:block>
                      $salesRow.var2
                 </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
     #end
```

What do i have to do with my data to access it in the .fo the way it is accesseds in the example ?

I think i have to use Xalan but i cant find any information how to to that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a velocity template, so you must either use velocity to preprocess it, or use XSLT (xalan). But if you want to use XSLT, you must first generate an XML document with all the data you need to generate the PDF.

UPDATE

for this example, you would need a document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<saleRows>
    <saleRow var1="..." var2="..."/>
    <saleRow var1="..." var2="..."/>
    ...
</saleRows>
```

or:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<saleRows>
    <saleRow>
        <var1>...</var1>
        <var2>...</var2>
    </saleRow>
    <saleRow>
        <var1>...</var1>
        <var2>...</var2>
    </saleRow>
    ...
</saleRows>
```